# What is the difference between locallang_db.xml and locallang_be.xml in TYPO3 CMS?

Tags: typo3

Some TYPO3 extensions are using a `locallang_be.xlf` *file for all kind of backend labels (e.g. FlexForms, backend modules etc.) but still split labels for TCA* in `locallang_db.xlf`.

There is no definition for `locallang_be.xml` in the official TYPO3 CMS documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FileStructure/Resources/Private/Language.html

Comment: That depends on you what you like: As the translation labels are referenced mostly with the full path (like LLL:EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Language/...) it's a matter of taste.
Personally, I would throw everything regarding TCA into one file and backend (for example, custom modules) into another file. But that's a matter of taste. You can also name your file like you want, personally I use Database.xlf for TCA-related stuff.
Only one exception: Name it locallang.xlf if you want to use the labels in frontend with Extbase, as then you can use the short label without the full path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common practice in TYPO3 to use different XLF files for backend labels, depending on the context. Here's a brief explanation of how these files are typically used:

locallang_be.xlf:
This file is often used for backend labels that are not related to specific records in the database (TCA). It may include labels for FlexForms, backend modules, and other backend-related elements.

locallang_db.xlf:
This file is commonly used for labels related to the TYPO3 Configuration Array (TCA). TCA defines the structure and properties of database tables, and locallang_db.xlf is where you'd find labels for fields, columns, and other elements specific to database records.

By separating these files, extension developers can organize translations more efficiently, making it easier for TYPO3 users and integrators to manage translations in different contexts.